# Inline list item box shifts up when it contains breaking words

Tags: html, css, html-lists

[image]

As you can see in the image Reference Check is shifting up because Reference Check label is breaking.

CSS

```
  .candidate-listing-sources {
         display: inline-block;
         border: 1px solid grey;
         width: 100px;
         height: 75px;
         padding-top: 5px;
         margin-right: 2px;
     }
```

HTML I am using Angular JS

```
<ul>
    <li class="candidate-listing-sources text-center"
        ng-repeat="source in candidateListingSources" 
        ng-click="loadCandidateListing(source.type)">
        <span>{{::source.label}}</span><br />
        <img ng-if="source.count === null" 
             ng-src="{{iconsUrl + '/loading.gif'}}" />
        <span ng-if="source.count !== null" class="badge">{{source.count}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Complete Rendered HTML in blank testing page

```
        <style type="text/css">
            .candidate-listing-sources {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid grey;
                width: 100px;
                height: 75px;
                padding-top: 5px;
                margin-right: 2px;
            }
        </style>
        <ul>
            <li class="candidate-listing-sources text-center">
                <span>Sourced</span><br>
                <span class="badge">0</span>
            </li>
            <li class="candidate-listing-sources text-center">
                <span>Breaking Words </span><br>
                <span class="badge">0</span>
            </li>
            <li class="candidate-listing-sources text-center">
                <span>OneWord</span><br>
                <span class="badge">0</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Is that all the relevant css you have?

Comment: yea I only have bootstrap's CSS included but that is pretty much it

Comment: Could you post rendered html, or setup fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` (or desired value), to CSS:

```
.candidate-listing-sources {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid grey;
                width: 100px;
                height: 75px;
                padding-top: 5px;
                margin-right: 2px;
       vertical-align:middle;
            }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gane8foL/

P.S. Hope that it will work with bootstrap CSS (not sure about whole CSS context).

Comment: Nice, i'm glad to help.